# How to use Google Docs as you would Dropbox (or any other online backup site)

Tags: sync, linux-mint, google-docs

What I would like to do is have files sync in the background with my Google Docs account, both up, and down.

Is there any way to do this? I use Mint 11, if it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://www.insynchq.com which support multiple Google Drive accounts and offline Google docs editing. It is available in multiple platforms (mac, windows, linux and mobile platforms).

Hope it helps!